# How can a Windows program temporarily change its time zone?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, timezone

I've written a function to return the `time_t` value corresponding to midnight on a given day. When there is no midnight for a given day, it returns the earliest time available; that situation can occur, for example, when Egypt enters daylight-saving time. This year, the time change takes effect at midnight on the night of April 29, so the clock goes directly from 23:59 to 01:00.

Now I'm writing unit tests for this function, and one of the tests should replicate the Egypt scenario. In Unix, I can accomplish it like this:

```
putenv("TZ", "Egypt", true);
tzset();
```

After doing that, further calls to `localtime` behave as if they're in Egypt instead of Minnesota, and my tests pass. Merely setting the environment variable doesn't have any effect on Windows, though. What can I do to make the unit test think it's somewhere else without affecting the rest of the programs running on the system?

Comment: whoosh.. maybe make a hook to change localtime's behavior for your tests instead?

Answer (score 4):

Check out **[_putenv_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyw7eyfw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** and **[_tzset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**. In theory, you should be able to set the **TZ** environment variable for your process with **_putenv_s** and then use **_tzset** to set the actual local time zone for your process to what the **TZ** environment variable is set to.

I know that this works on Linux with **putenv** and **tzset**, and from the documentation of **_putenv_s** and **_tzset**, it appears that you should be able to do the same with them on Windows. I haven't actually tried it though.

Answer (score 3):

Use Isolation/Mocking framework - the only one I know of at the moment is [Isolator++](http://site.typemock.com/isolatorpp-user-guide-index/) which is currently in beta, I'm sure that you can get a copy by asking for one from the good people of Typemock.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't call SetTimeZoneInformation - there is no thread or process-specific notion of a time zone in Windows. As others say, the easiest way is to mock out the timezone code - with Pex/Mocks, you can mock out even static methods, which means you can hook the standard .NET Timezone code to replace it with your own. If you're using C/C++, you just need to wire up the code to have the TZ info be mockable.

Answer (score 1):

With VS 2008 (C++ native) I was able to modify the behavior of `localtime()` by changing the  `_timezone` variable.

I agree, this is not a clean way to do, but at least this could be a workaround.

Of course, you need to do the math by yourself to find the number of seconds between UTC and your 'new' timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I used `setlocale(LC_ALL, "deu_aut")` to switch the language/country settings to Austria - declared in `locale.h`. Sadly i haven't found a language/country string for egypt, but perhaps this gives you a hint.

Comment: The language and country for Egypt is `ar_EG` (for *Arabic*). But those settings don't affect the time zone. They can affect the format used to display the current time, but that's not really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same requirement:

->some processes must be stuck to UTC and others to some timezone different from the Windows system timezone

After months of (*interrupted*) study I fall to the conclusion that on Windows it is only possible to set "UTC" or "current" system time zone. So only the following may be done:

```
     - set TZ="UTC" 
     - unset TZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a hook to GetTimeZoneInformation, which overrides system data with your own preferences.

Answer (score -2):

Have you seen the [SetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724944(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API function?

Comment: Doesn't that change the time zone for the entire OS? I want something limited to the current process (or thread), suitable for use in a unit test.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, it affects the entire machine. To my knowledge, there's not thread-local version. However, if it's just for unit testing purposes then that may still be ok if you restore the original time zone in your test teardown method.

Comment: Perhaps my employer has a different philosophy about unit tests than you do. If something changes system-wide settings, it's no longer classified as a unit test, and it won't get run as part of the build process. Many people could be using the same build server, and their tests shouldn't interfere with each other.